# Odoo Qweb report header overlapping body

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-13

I'm creating a Qweb report that it´s header depends on the company address, and it´s parent company address. This information has to be in a thin column that ends up overlapping the body content. Are there css classes that could make the body move downwards automatically?

Comment: Can you please share any screenshot? I think you should increase the header space in Paper format.

Comment: You can play with the paper format margins and the header spacing in `Technical -> Reporting -> Paper Format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Kenly and @Younis Mahsud, I was able to fix the overlapping by changing the value of the fields "margin_top" and "header_spacing".
I've added to my module an xml file defining my specific header spacing and margin to a couple of reports like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<odoo>

    <record id="my_new_paper_format" model="report.paperformat">
        <field name="name">My custom paperformat</field>
        <field name="format">Letter</field>
        <field name="orientation">Portrait</field>
        <field name="margin_top">55</field>
        <field name="margin_bottom">10</field>
        <field name="margin_left">7</field>
        <field name="margin_right">7</field>
        <field name="header_line" eval="False"/>
        <field name="header_spacing">50</field>
        <field name="dpi">90</field>
        <field name="report_ids" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('report_action_id_1'), ref('report_action_id_2')])]"/>
    </record>

</odoo>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this , the header_spacing thing resolved my problem. Thank you man.